# IPad app to synchronize documents, while limiting the ability to share them

Tags: file-synchronization, cloud-storage, ipad-app

i need a suggestion for this kind of app for iPad,

1. It works like dropbox, but all document on iPad cannot be shared (create a duplicate in iPad/send as attachment/Bluetooth).
2. And the document will be updated in the cloud by administrator.
3. If there are any update, iPad users have to sync (manually/automatically).

Does dropbox pro has this kind of features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*all document on iPad cannot be shared by any means*": For instance, if it is an image, I can't view it? (as it would allow me to take a picture of it with a camera)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for your comment, i already edit my question. :)